# How do I implement HTTPS in an ASP.NET Project?

Tags: asp.net

I want to implement HTTPS in my ASP.NET application. How do I do it?

Answer (score 3):

HTTPS need not be implemented within the code itself. As long as the code runs under a server that is implementing the SSL, you will have no problem.

Have a look here: [Setting up SSL correctly with IIS and ASP.NET](http://weblogs.asp.net/pwilson/archive/2004/12/23/331455.aspx)

The only thing is to make sure that any code that calls another page should also be under the SSL site, otherwise users will be given warnings. This especially is overlooked with images.

Answer (score 1):

You could start looking at [How To Set Up an HTTPS Service in IIS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324069)

Maybe this question is better answered in http://www.serverfault.com